# Give a user access to a database, but not to containing folder

Tags: bash, permissions, database

I am making a program in python that stores and modifies the stock of a little shop, using SQLite databases.

Each employer is going to be a user at a Linux system, and a user at the program. As the program modifies databases, I need every user to have write and read permissions on databases.

The program has a terminal included, so I will make a bash script to allow root to execute, eg: `>db` which will open databases folder for a quick inventory etc. 
But I want not to allow some commands as this to employers. The problem is if I quit permissions to the containing folder for the employers with `chmod`, user is then not allowed to use the program (`sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`).

Can I achieve that? Maybe with bash scripts?

Comment: This is my first program and I have never packed one into a tar.gz.I don't know what happens exactly with the folders when packing, and if that final step is also related with the solution of the trouble.

Comment: There may be a way to do it with suitable *group* permissions and memberships - but you will need to be a lot more specific about your requirements. OTOH you should ask yourself whether SQLite (AFAIK a *serverless* SQL implementation) is really the appropriate backend for this application - or whether you would be better using a client-server database in which you could implement fine grained access control on the server side

Comment: No server side. Databases are gonna be stored at the shop's computer. I suposse when installed I will have too the DB folder at the installation directory, so I need to avoid access to the employers to that folder, while having permissions to the .db files to use the software.

Comment: I have tried quiting executing permissions, but to open a database I have realized is not to execute it. ¿maybe quit permissions to install any program and permissions to use SQLBrowser software?

Comment: and I think to make not working the bash command >db will be easy to set

Comment: but problem if I am not wrong is if the employer knows a bit linux system he could find the path (at opt probably), and not only delete a database (not a big trouble, copies at the cloud), but to distorsionate the shop database at home! (cause he disagrees with his boss eg)

Comment: Your work and the script or process you provide to your users will be a huge task on your part.  One of the purposes of SQLite is for its quick time savings in setup and operation.  Based on the details you are trying to implement, I believe you would save substantially more time by moving to Msql.  With that, the user will only have the access you provide.  The detail you want restricted away from the user will be totally invisible and unavailable to the users.  Is there something particular that's ruling out a regular full-featured database?

Comment: For my particular society it is not a trouble, all employers are partners. But I want to say my program is safe, an angry employer could not disturb the shop system.

Comment: I dunno about all this but for a few hundred dollars I'm sure you can buy a Point of Sale system (POS) with Inventory Control, Accounts Payable, Accounts Receivable and  General Ledger for a small shop. Then it's probably a couple hundred more for multi-user per seat.

Comment: Yes I know it. We want to shale integral cheap system with cash machine, tickets....

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way, or a partial solution. From this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82347/how-to-check-if-a-user-can-access-a-given-file
stat and inotifywait commands doesn't help because they give the same output regardless user is accesing to the folder or just using the programm.
But maybe audit can help me. Communicating with a subproccess of the programm I can send an alert to the root at the program saying "user acceded to database folder", while the shoper is gonna be the only one one who makes copies of db, at the cloud in my case.